# Is there any way to add passing-by-reference to this code?

Tags: c++

Student here.  I'm missing a single rubric item in the following project program and can't figure out where to place it, "it" being a pass-by-reference item.  If anyone is feeling generous, please take a look at my program below and give me a heads-up about where I could tweak the code to make pass-by-reference possible.  As it stands, I'm stumped and I don't have enough time to come up with an entirely new problem for which to code a solution.  Thank you all in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Global Variable
int height = 0;

//Function Prototypes
int getMale();
int getFemale();

int main()
{

    //Local Variable
    int ideal = 0;
    char sex(' ');

    //Sequence Structure
    cout << "Welcome to the Hamwi Ideal Body Weight Equation Calculator!" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your height in inches (remember, 1 foot = 12 inches): " << endl;
    cin >> height;

    cout << "Please enter your biological sex (M or F): " << endl;
    cin >> sex;

    //Repetition Structure
    while (toupper(sex) != 'M' && 'F')
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry. Please enter your biological sex (M or F): " << endl;
        cin >> sex;
    } //end while

    //Selection Structure
    if (toupper(sex) == 'M')
    {
        int ideal = getMale();
        cout << "Thank you. Your ideal body weight is approximately: " << ideal << " pounds." << endl;
        cout << "Have a nice day!" << endl;
    } //end if

    else
    {
        int ideal = getFemale();
        cout << "Thank you. Your ideal body weight is approximately: " << ideal << " pounds." << endl;
        cout << "Have a nice day!" << endl;
    } //end else

    return 0;
} //end of main function

//Program-Defined Function #1 (Male)
int getMale()
{
    //Local Variable
    int male = 0;

    if (height >= 60)
    {
        male = 106 + ((height - 60) * 6);
        return male;
    } //end if

    else
    {
        male = 106 - ((60 - height) * 6);
        return male;
    } //end else
} //end of male function

//Program-Defined Function #2 (Female)
int getFemale()
{
    //Local Variable
    int female = 0;

    if (height >= 60)
    {
        female = 100 + ((height - 60) * 5);
        return female;
    } //end if

    else
    {
        female = 100 - ((60 - height) * 5);
        return female;
    } //end else
} //end of female function
```

Comment: Why do you think you need pass by reference?

Comment: It's a rubric item (grading rubric).  Mandatory item for the project.

Comment: Make height a local variable in your main function, and then pass it to your functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move variable `height` to `main()` (make it local) and pass it by reference to all your functions. Actually, I'd say that would be a better style than passing data through global variables.

But in a real project it's typically better to think of what behavior you want from your program, not of what awesome language features you want to use.

Comment: That's a good idea!  I still struggle with the prototype & header lines for program-defined functions, though.  I spent a good 2 hours tonight trying to get the 2 functions I have to actually work.  If I want to pass-by-reference for height, would my prototype & header look like this:

int getMale(int &height);      //and
int getMale(int &height)       //???

Comment: Yes, you can use the prototypes you wrote, but that would be better to use `int getMale(const int& height)` - the const reference is used to add an additional compiler check to forbid you change the `height` inside the function.

Comment: It depends on the behavior you want, though.  For example, if you want to return multiple values from your function (which is impossible to do directly), you could simply pass multiple references in and then "return" multiple values by modifying the reference parameters.

Comment: @Travis If you want to return multiple values, it's better to use `std::tuple`. Here, the function `getMale` obviously should not change the `height` passed. If it does, it's very unexpected for the reader and the refactoring is desirable.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I completely agree regarding the OP's given case.  But the option may be valid for other cases.  (I've never come across any personally, though... at least not in C++ anyway)  I just wanted to pass along the idea.

Comment: @CVHansen edit in your updated code so we can have a look

Comment: @CVHansen Not sure I understand your "while loop stopped functioning" means. Try using the line-by-line debug with the "watches" window opened in your favorite IDE, and, if struck, create another question showing what you managed to find.

Answer (score 2):

You pass `height` by reference in one of your gender functions.

For example:

```
int getMale(int &height) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

And then simply call it by:

```
getMale(height);
```

Also, are you required go use a global variable?  If not, then make `height` a local variable in your `main` as other commenters have stated.  Global variables are considered bad style, as they can cause hard-to-diagnose problems when you're working on a much larger project.

Comment: Global variables are a no-no.  Good to know!  Thank you, Travis.

Comment: One exception is global *constants*.  Since constants can't be modified, they can safely be made global without running into the same problems that global variables have.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your two functions like this

```
int getMale   ( int& height );
int getFemale ( int& height );
```

And in your main you declare a variable that you can pass to the functions

```
int main()
{
    // Declare here instead of globally
    int height = 0;

    // Then you can call
    int result = getMale(height);
        result = getFemale(height);
}
```

It will behave the same way. It is considered better practice to pass by reference than to use a global variable, so kudos to you for asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this program not giving you the correct answer and that's why you want to pass by reference? or what is the exact situation? 
Anyways in order for you to pass by reference then you remove height from being a global variable and have it local in your main, then for your prototypes include a reference parameter then when you call them in main pass your local variable.
This is example of how pass by reference would work.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//Prototype
void add(int num1, int num2, int &res);
int main()
{
    int res;
    add(1, 2, res);
    cout<<"I got the value by passing my variable by reference"<<res<<endl;
    return 0;
}
void add(int num1, int num2, int &res)
{
    res = num1 + num2;
}
```